How to force delete recent opened file session on Visual Studio Code with unsaved file?
Normally we could delete the session by clicking the "X" button on the "recent open list" on the right side. However, this time I am trying the delete a session with some unsaved files on a remote SSH connection.
It pops a message "Folders with unsaved files cannot be removed until all unsaved files have been saved or reverted".
But the server have been destroyed. I can no longer connect to that remote SSH again. Is there a way to delete this record manually?
